# Encoding in PHP

Tags: php

I have made a private website with a contact form which sends an html mail to me. But there is a problem with getting mails. Instead of "ä", "ö" or "ü" I get "?"-signs.

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
    /* variables */
    $error       = '';
    $headers     = '';
    $empfaenger  = '';
    $mail        = '';
    $subject     = '';
    $message     = '';
    $anrede      = '';
    $name        = '';
    $vorname     = '';
    $firma       = '';
    $strasse     = '';
    $nr          = '';
    $plz         = '';
    $ort         = '';
    $land        = '';
    $telefon     = '';
    $fax         = '';
    $REMOTE_ADDR = '';


    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        /* Anrede */
        $anrede = $_POST['anrede'];

        /* Nachname */
        $name = $_POST['name'];

        /* Vorname*/
        $vorname = $_POST['vorname'];

        /* Firma */
        $firma = $_POST['firma'];

        /* Strasse */
        $strasse = $_POST['strasse'];

        /* Nr */
        $nr = $_POST['nr'];

        /* PLZ */
        $plz = $_POST['plz'];

        /* Ort */
        $ort = $_POST['ort'];

        /* Land */
        $land = $_POST['land'];

        /* Telefonnummer */
        $telefon = $_POST['telefon'];

        /* Fax */
        $fax = $_POST['fax'];

        /* Empfänger */
        $empfaenger = 'office@awidal.com';

        /* Absender */
        $mail = $_POST['mail'];

        /* Text */
        $text = $_POST['text'];

        /* Betreff */
        $subject = 'Kontaktformular Webseite';

        /* Nachricht zusammensetzen (HTML-Email) */
        $message = '<html>
                                <head>
                                    <title>Kontaktformular</title>
                                    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                                    </head>
                                    <body>
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2"><b>Kontaktformular</b></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Name</td>
                                            <td>' . $anrede . '&nbsp;' . $name . '&nbsp;' . $vorname . '</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Firma</td>
                                            <td>' . $firma . '</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Strasse/Nr</td>
                                            <td>' . $strasse . '&nbsp;' . $nr . '</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>PLZ/Ort</td>
                                            <td>' . $plz . '&nbsp;' . $ort . '</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Land</td>
                                            <td>' . $land . '</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Telefon</td>
                                            <td>' . $telefon . '</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Fax</td>
                                            <td>' . $fax . '</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>E-mail</td>
                                            <td>' . $mail . '</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Nachricht</td>
                                            <td>' . $text . '</td>
                                        </tr>
                                </table>
                                </body>
                                </html>';


        /* Header der Mail zusammenbauen */
        $headers .= 'From:' . $mail . "\n";
        /* $headers .= 'Reply-To:' . $reply . "\n"; */
        $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\n";
        $headers .= 'X-Sender-IP: ' . $REMOTE_ADDR . "\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\n";

        function convertUmlaute($mess)
        {
            /* Umlaute konvertieren */
            $pattern1  = "/�/";
            $replace1  = "&auml;"; // &#228
            $mess      = preg_replace($pattern1, $replace1, $mess);
            $pattern2  = "/�/";
            $replace2  = "&ouml;"; // &#246
            $mess      = preg_replace($pattern2, $replace2, $mess);
            $pattern3  = "/�/";
            $replace3  = "&uuml;"; // &#252
            $mess      = preg_replace($pattern3, $replace3, $mess);
            $pattern1a = "/�/";
            $replace1a = "&Auml;"; // &#196
            $mess      = preg_replace($pattern1a, $replace1a, $mess);
            $pattern2a = "/�/";
            $replace2a = "&Ouml;"; // &#214
            $mess      = preg_replace($pattern2a, $replace2a, $mess);
            $pattern3a = "/�/";
            $replace3a = "&Uuml;"; // &#220
            $mess      = preg_replace($pattern3a, $replace3a, $mess);
            $pattern4  = "/�/";
            $replace4  = "&#Eacute;";
            $mess      = preg_replace($pattern4, $replace4, $mess);
            $pattern4a = "/�/";
            $replace4a = "&eacute;";
            $mess      = preg_replace($pattern4a, $replace4a, $mess);
            return $mess;
        }

        convertUmlaute($message);

        /* Variablen, um Eingaben des Formulars zu überprüfen */
        $ok_firma   = 0;
        $ok_anrede  = 0;
        $ok_name    = 0;
        $ok_vorname = 0;
        $ok_strasse = 0;
        $ok_nr      = 0;
        $ok_plz     = 0;
        $ok_ort     = 0;
        $ok_mail    = 0;
        $ok_text    = 0;

        /* Variable, welche den gültigen Bereich der Postleitzahl (PLZ) setzt */
        $int_options = array(
            "options" => array(
                "min_range" => 1000,
                "max_range" => 99999
            )
        );

        /* Schaut, dass im Minimum die Pflichtfelder ausgefüllt sind */
        if (empty($name) OR empty($vorname) OR empty($mail) OR empty($text) OR empty($anrede)) {
            echo '<p style="color:red">&nbsp;Sie haben nicht alle Pflichfelder ausgef&uuml;llt!</p>';
        } else {
            $ok_anrede = 1;
            $ok_text   = 1;

            /* Überprüft den Wert des Feldes NACHNAME */
            if (filter_var($name, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
                echo '<p style="color:red">&nbsp;Das Feld <b>Nachname</b> darf nur aus Buchstaben bestehen!</p>';
            } else {
                $ok_name = 1;
            }

            /* Überprüft den Wert des Feldes VORNAME */
            if (filter_var($vorname, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
                echo '<p style="color:red">&nbsp;Das Feld <b>Vorname</b> darf nur aus Buchstaben bestehen!</p>';
            } else {
                $ok_vorname = 1;
            }

            /* Überprüft, ob eine korrekte EMAIL eingegeben wurde */
            if (!filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                echo '<p style="color:red">&nbsp;Bitte geben Sie eine korrekte Email-Adresse ein!</p>';
            }

            else {
                $ok_mail = 1;
            }

            /* Überprüft den Wert des Feldes FIRMA */
            if (!empty($firma)) {
                if (filter_var($firma, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
                    echo '<p style="color:red">&nbsp;Das Feld <b>Firma</b> darf nicht nur aus Zahlen bestehen!</p>';
                } else {
                    $ok_firma = 1;
                }
            } else {
                $ok_firma = 1;
            }

            /* Überprüft den Wert des Feldes STRASSE */
            if (!empty($strasse)) {
                if (filter_var($strasse, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
                    echo '<p style="color:red">&nbsp;Das Feld <b>Strasse</b> darf nur aus Buchstaben bestehen!</p>';
                } else {
                    $ok_strasse = 1;
                }
            } else {
                $ok_strasse = 1;
            }

            /* Überprüft den Wert des Feldes NR */
            if (!empty($nr)) {
                if (!filter_var($nr, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
                    echo '<p style="color:red">&nbsp;Das Feld <b>Nr</b> darf nur aus Zahlen bestehen!</p>';
                } else {
                    $ok_nr = 1;
                }
            } else {
                $ok_nr = 1;
            }

            /* Überprüft den Wert des Feldes PLZ */
            if (!empty($plz)) {
                if (!filter_var($plz, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $int_options)) {
                    echo '<p style="color:red">&nbsp;Das Feld <b>PLZ</b> darf nur aus Zahlen im Bereich von 1000 bis 99999 bestehen!</p>';
                } else {
                    $ok_plz = 1;
                }
            } else {
                $ok_plz = 1;
            }

            /* Überprüft den Wert des Feldes ORT */
            if (!empty($ort)) {
                if (filter_var($ort, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
                    echo '<p style="color:red">&nbsp;Das Feld <b>Ort</b> darf nur aus Buchstaben bestehen!</p>';
                } else {
                    $ok_ort = 1;
                }
            } else {
                $ok_ort = 1;
            }

            /* Mail wird gesendet, falls alle Eingaben korrekt sind und den definierten Werten bzw. Datentypen entsprechen */
            if (($ok_anrede + $ok_text + $ok_name + $ok_vorname + $ok_mail + $ok_firma + $ok_strasse + $ok_nr + $ok_plz + $ok_ort) == 10) {
                mail($empfaenger, $subject, $message, $headers);
                echo '<p style="color:red">&nbsp;Mail erfolgreich gesendet!</p>';
            } else {
                echo '<p style="color:red">&nbsp;Mail konnte nicht gesendet werden!</p>';
            }

        }
    }
    ?>
```

In the php-function `convertUmlaute($mess)` you can see ?-signs. In my php code these are squares.

Can you help me?

Comment: And, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Hint: By writing *"converting the mutations"* you will address something totally different the common programmer here on this website will understand. After saying so, it might be the right time that you start to learn about this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: In mails I get only "?"-signs instead of "ä", "ö" or "ü".

Comment: @Asator: Yes you do. And there is another news to you: By creating the code example here, you've also created ?'s *already in the source-code* (!). That's why it's so important you now start to learn about charsets. Otherwise it's hard to talk with you about the problem.

Comment: By "mutations" do you mean "Umlauts"?

Comment: @Astor what you mean is "I have encoding problems". It would be advisable to make everything UTF8 - then you don't need to recode/modify/"mutate" anything.

Comment: @georg: Yes, I mean "Umlaute".

Comment: How do you expect the function `convertUmlaute` to work?????

Comment: @Asator: Which characterset are you using for the form? (Compare with: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-forms-utf-8 )

Comment: Also take care that your script is prone to mail header injection. You need to fix that first as it can be used to distribute spam emails via your server. But that's a bit  misleading. For the question itself, please reduce the code to a new example, re-written from scratch that just demonstrates with as little code and data as necessary your issue.

Comment: @Mithrandir: If the html mail gets ä ö or ü, they will be converted to &auml; and so on.

Comment: @Asator: PHP has a function for that built in, no need to re-invent the wheel. The function is called [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities).

Comment: @Asator: i know what you want to do, i just wonder how you expect your function to work properly! And you are re-inventing an existing function, badly i might add!

Comment: @hakre: With the htmlentities-function it works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructing a E-Mail header, which renders correctly in every Mail-Client is not that easy.

**Consider using a library like phpmailer.**

It seems to be a charset-encoding problem. You don't need your *"messy"* `convertUmlaute()` function...

Just change some lines in your **E-Mail header**:

Change

```
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\n";
```

into:

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\n"; 
// better style of "\n"
```

Or for testing

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . "\n";
```

BTW: The correct english term for that german 'Umlaut' 'ä', 'ö', 'ü' is *mutated vowel*

Comment: I have added this: <meta charset="UTF-8"> and it doesn't function.

Comment: It works now. I have added <meta charset="UTF-8"> and took the htmlentities function instead of the self created function. Thank you very much!